# How to get first level super class in freemarker template by java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, freemarker

suppose that i have a these below classes:

```
public abstract class A<T>  implements Serializable {

}

public class B extends A<Long> {

}

public class C extends B {

}

public class D {
     public C c;
}
```

then, i want to generate code using these below codes and template:

```
private static void generateJavaCode(Class clazz) {
        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("E:/templates/code/"));
            cfg.setTemplateLoader(ftl1);

            Template template = cfg.getTemplate(tmpl);
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            String modelPackage = clazz.getPackage().getName();

            data.put("fields", clazz.getDeclaredFields());

            File f = new File(filePath);
            String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            String ffilePath = absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
            new File(ffilePath).mkdirs();
            Writer file = new FileWriter(f);
            template.process(data, file);
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

and this is the content of `.ftl` file:

```
<#list fields as field>
    <#attempt>
         field.superclass.superclass
    <#recover>
         field.superclass
    </#attempt>
</#list>
```

but `field.superclass.superclass` doesn't work, how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your *"clazz"* variable is a instance of the *"D"* class you declared. With:

```
data.put("fields", clazz.getDeclaredFields());
```

you assign to "fields" the Field[] object (returned from [Class.getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields())), not a Class[]. As the [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class does not have a 'superclass' getter, your code in .ftl causes an exception:

```
${field.superclass} // it does not work
```

but Field class has a method [getDeclaringClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaringClass()), which gives a Class reference. then you can call it from your freemarker as follow:

```
${field.declaringClass // return: C 
${field.declaringClass.superclass} // return: B
${field.declaringClass.superclass.superclass} // return: A
```